# C++ server recieving too many request, i want to accept some number of request at a time

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have developed a server in c++ that recieves number of request at a time, i want to process few request at a time, say 5 request first then next 5 request & so on in order to reduce the burden on my server, can anyone help me out how can i restrict the request?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please take some time to read
[the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) is.

Comment: You questions is too vague without code samples. problem descriptions and descriptions of what you yourself have already tried. 
As for a starting place... process your requests using a fixed number of threads (google: threads, producer-consumer).

Comment: When you know what you have in mind, you can easily think you've described it well when there're actually huge missing details.  Most glaringly, are you talking about TCP, UDP, MQ, or some other manner of request?  If TCP - is there 1 transient connection per connection, or does the connection stay alive across multiple requests?  If the former, is it ok to not accept the client connections until you're ready to process them, or do you want to accept as soon as possible?  Does it matter whether you let flow control prevent the client sending too much of the request vs buffer before processing?

Comment: I don't have code at present, but the scenario is, number of requests are coming in form of multiple threads to server, my problem is : my code allocates some buffers from heap and do some operations on that buffer and then dealalocates it, the issue is before i deallocate the exisitng buffer number of other request allocates buffer & hence my heap size goes high drastically, so i want to handle few request at time, can counting semaphore will be helpfull ? i hope u got the problem now.

Comment: You may want to use some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)

Answer (score 0):

You need a queue.
Store all the requests in the queue and process it in whatever pace you want.